# Why does GNU make process hangs up?

Tags: makefile, cygwin, windows-10, gnu-make, ds-5

*TL;DR:*

On a fresh Windows 10 installation, I installed ARM DS-5 v5.26.2 development tools. I am using its `make.exe` to build our project, either from Cygwin command line or from the Eclipse IDE's build settings.

Our Makefile contains the line:

```
uname_result := $(shell uname -s)
```

but whenever `make` reaches this line, it gets stuck. This happens on bash terminal as well as on Window's command prompt.

**UPDATE 3:**

After more troubleshooting, it appears that the problem was the DS-5's `make` utility itself. I added `make` to my Cygwin installation, and used that one instead, and now my builds run OK.

Now the question is why the ARM's version does not work on my Win 10 machine, where it used to work fine on Win 7.

---

*Long version:*

I had just went through a clean install of Windows 10 on my work PC, after using Windows 7 for two years on that PC. In the last two days I am going through the process of reinstalling our tools and getting back in shape. Unfortunately, I am now stuck with `make` giving me headaches.

We develop embedded firmware using ARM's DS-5 toolset. The project is a Makefile Project, so we do not use the built-in Eclipse builder. In order to build the project outside of the Eclipse environment, I installed `Cygwin` for a convenient `bash` CLI. Both `make` and `clang` are a part of the DS-5 installation.

When I run `make` on the project's `Makefile` form CLI, the execution gets stuck indefinitely.

[... removing a long story following the problem revealing process ...]

After tracking down the source of the problem, I found out that the problem is with this line:

```
uname_result := $(shell uname -s 2>NUL)
```

In order to simplify it, I verified that the problem is the `shell` command itself. I made a very simple `Makefile` with the following command that gets stuck as well:

```
uname_result := $(shell ls)
```

When processing the makefile with `make -d`, as it gets to that line, I get the following:

```
CreateProcess(C:\cygwin64\bin\ls.exe,ls,...)
Main thread handle = 000000000000009C
```

Why can't `make` execute the `shell` command? This exact same script used to be working just fine before the migration.

**UPDATE 1 w/ more info:**

There is only one `make.exe` on my system, placed at `C:\DS-5_v5.26.2\bin`.

I created a simplified makefile, `Makefile.tmp`:

```
.PHONY: help
help:
    echo ====================== TESTING ======================
    uname_result := $(shell ls)
```

I process this makefile from Cygwin's bash CLI:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/DS-5_v5.26.2/bin/make -d -f Makefile.tmp help
```

and I get tons of diagnostics in return:

```
GNU Make 4.1
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
find_and_set_shell() path search set default_shell = C:/cygwin64/bin/sh.exe
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'Makefile.tmp'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.o'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.c'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.cc'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.C'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.cpp'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.p'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.f'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.F'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.m'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.r'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.s'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.S'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.mod'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.sh'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.o'.
  Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.o'.
   Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.cc'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.C'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.cpp'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.p'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.f'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.F'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.m'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.r'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.s'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.S'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.mod'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.o,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.o,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.c'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.c'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.y'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.l'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.c,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.c,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.y'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.y'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.y,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.y,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.y'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.y'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.y'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.l'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.l'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.l,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.l,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.l'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.l'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.l'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.w'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.w'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.w,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.w,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.w'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.w'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.w'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.cc'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.cc'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.cc,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.cc,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.cc'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.cc'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.cc'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.C'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.C'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.C,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.C,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.C'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.C'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.C'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.cpp'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.cpp'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.cpp,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.cpp,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.cpp'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.cpp'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.cpp'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.p'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.p'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.web'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.p,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.p,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.p'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.p'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.p'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.web'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.web'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.web,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.web,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.web'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.web'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.web'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.f'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.f'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.F'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.r'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.f,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.f,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.f'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.f'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.f'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.F'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.F'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.F,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.F,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.F'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.F'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.F'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.r'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.r'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
     Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.l'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.r,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.r,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.r'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.r'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.r'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.F'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.m'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.m'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.ym'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.m,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.m,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.m'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.m'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.m'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.ym'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.ym'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.ym,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.ym,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.ym'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.ym'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.ym'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.r'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.s'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.s'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.S'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.s,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.s,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.s'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.s'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.s'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.S'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.S'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.S,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.S,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.S'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.S'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.S'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.S'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.mod'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.mod'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.mod,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.mod,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.mod'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.mod'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.mod'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.c'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.cc'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.C'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.cpp'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.p'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.f'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.F'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.m'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.r'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.s'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.S'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.mod'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.sh'.
  Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.tmp.sh'.
   Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.tmp.sh,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.sh,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.tmp.sh'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.tmp.sh'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.sh'.
  No implicit rule found for 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'Makefile.tmp'.
 No need to remake target 'Makefile.tmp'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'help'.
 File 'help' does not exist.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'help'.
Must remake target 'help'.
CreateProcess(C:\cygwin64\bin\ls.exe,ls,...)
Main thread handle = 000000000000008C
```

but what's important is probably the first and last parts:

```
GNU Make 4.1
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
find_and_set_shell() path search set default_shell = C:/cygwin64/bin/sh.exe
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'Makefile.tmp'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.tmp'.
. . . . 
. . . . 
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.tmp.sh'.
  No implicit rule found for 'Makefile.tmp'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'Makefile.tmp'.
 No need to remake target 'Makefile.tmp'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'help'.
 File 'help' does not exist.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'help'.
Must remake target 'help'.
CreateProcess(C:\cygwin64\bin\ls.exe,ls,...)
Main thread handle = 000000000000008C
```

So, as you can see, it does not perform neither the `echo` command nor the `ls` command. If I comment out the `shell` command, I see the `TESTING` message echoed to the terminal.

Obviously, DS-5's `make.exe` was built for Windows. Should there be a problem calling it from Cygwin bash? If so, how come this worked well on the Win 7 machine?

**UPDATE 2 w/ more info:**

I repeated the test, this time running from Windows' `CMD` prompt. I replaced the `ls` command in the b`shell` line with a `dir` command. Surprisingly, the same behavior is happening on `CMD` too!

So, apparently, the problem *is* with `make`'s `shell` function invocation.

Comment: Do you have another make in the path ? `Main thread handle` is NOT in the cygwin make only on Windows build

Comment: @matzeri - AFAICT, the only `make.exe` I have is in `C:\DS-5_v5.26.2\bin`. Moreover, in the shell script I use to invoke make, I explicitly have the full path to that make program.

Comment: Updated question with more info.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? I have the exact same problem with DS-5 5.23.1

Comment: @Satrapes - Did you read Update 3 of the TL;DR? I am using Cygwin's `make` instead of the one that's included with DS-5.

Comment: Yes thanks for that, I have done the same but I was just wondering if you ever got around to finding why the DS5 make doesn't work.

Comment: @Satrapes - No, unfortunately. Once I got my flow working, I left this problem behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contact with ARM support I got the following reply:

```
With regards to the problem you are seeing this is a known issue with GNU 
make version 4.1 supplied by ARM with DS5.  This version of make was shipped 
with DS5 versions 5.23 to 5.26. DS5-5.22 used make 3.81, and DS5-5.27 and 
later have used make 4.2 - neither of which suffer from this defect.

There are three possible workarounds in your case:
1 - Avoid using the "shell" command in your make script - this is probably 
not ideal!
2 - Upgrade your DS-5 version to 5.27 or later - this may or may not be an 
option for you.
3 - Download[*] a different version of GNU make and use it in place of the 
version 3.81 that was supplied with your current version of DS-5.

[*] - Although make is freely available under GPL, unfortunately there are 
legal implications involved with its redistribution which is why I can't 
simply email you an alternative version of make.
```

Thanks to Alex from ARM support for this.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this. Essentially, his 3rd suggestion is the solution that worked for me, using Cygwin's make.